# How to create JQuery Mobile second page to call function only once?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

Actually i wish to call the function james() only once on the first click to page 2  and in the consecutive next click to 2nd page  , i dont want to call the function james(). but it call every time i call page 2.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="">
    <head>
       

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css">

 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
             <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
         

 <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
               var Clicked = false;

               function james() {
                  if(Clicked === false){

                        alert("james");
                  }
                Clicked=true;      
             }
                

   </script>

    </head>
    <body>
 
    <div data-role="page" id="pagetwo" >

     <a href="#pageone" onClick="james(); this.onClick=null;">Go to Page two</a>
               
       </div>
            



    <div data-role="page" id="pageone">
  
        <a href="#pagetwo">Go to Page one</a>
  
    </div>        

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done easily in jQuery Mobile.

If you need to execute certain code only once during page initialization you can use jQuery mobile page event called [pagecreate](https://api.jquerymobile.com/pagecreate/).

This event will trigger only once during the first page initialization.

```
$( document ).on( "pagecreate", "#secondPage", function( event ) {
  alert( "This page was just enhanced by jQuery Mobile!" );
});
```

And here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/u2tw371o/

Answer (score 0):

brother just initialize your variable globaly in java script as shown below

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
   var Clicked = false;
           function james() {
              if(Clicked === false){

                    alert("james");
              }
            Clicked=true;      
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is `.one` event binding method in jquery. Don't know if that is what you need.

```
$( "#pageone" ).one( "click", james);
```

The `james` function is only run ONCE for each element.

Reference: http://api.jquery.com/one/